# What's the accepted Python style for long tuples on the left-hand side of for loops?

Tags: python

I'm traversing all combinations of many possible (very unrelated) parameters. If we have 7 such parameters, we might have something like

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'banana']
letter_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
class_list = [SomeClass, AnotherClass]
list_list = ...
dict_list = ...
animal_list = ...
language_list = ...

combinations = itertools.product(fruit_list, letter_list, ...)

for i, (fruit, letter, class_, list_, dict_, animal, language) in enumerate(combinations):
    ...
```

Two questions: First, is there a more canonical way of doing this in the first place? We could have many nested for loops, but this is just as gross. Second, if we're stuck with this, what style is best for breaking up the tuple in the for loop? I don't think this matches anything in PEP 8.

Comment: Since PEP 8 doesn't say, it's up to your (or somebody's else) opinion (well it is anyway). It's basically opinion based question. Do whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking the tuple inside the loop looks better:

```
for i, values in enumerate(combinations):
  fruit, letter, class_, list_, dict_, animal, language = values
```

Comment: My very related question would be, what happens if still that line doesn't fit say within 80 chars? What's accepted Python style for breaking a left-hand side tuple up?

Comment: That's the ride-hand side, which is the common case. I've never seen the left-hand side case.

Comment: Use can use `\\` or parentheses in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The way I always do this is something like this:

```
for i, (
        fruit,
        letter,
        ...
        language) in enumerate(combinations):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

PEP8 gives examples for similar situations [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).
It is prefered to use parentheses and not backslash:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

So, regarding your code: once the line reaches 79 chars, break it after the comma in parentheses and start a new line, aligning it with the opening parenthesis, or with double indentation (i.e. 8 spaces) in order not to confuse the `for` statement and it's body. However, aligning to parenthesis is the prefered way.

In this particular example, wrap it like this:

```
for i, (fruit, letter, class_, list_, dict_, animal, language) in 
        enumerate(combinations):
    ...
```

considering you might need to break long tuple, e.g.:

```
for i, (fruit, letter, class_, 
        list_, dict_, animal, language
        ) in enumerate(combinations):
    ...
```